# ACC2010: date picker in restricted folder not available

Tags: ms-access

If an MS Access .mdb or .accdb file (assume front end db, data elsewhere) is placed in a folder where the user's permissions are limited to read & execute and the file is opened by ACC2007 or greater, the built-in date picker is not available.  Is there a workaround other than elevating the user's permissions (either for that folder or moving to a folder where permissions are elevated)?

Comment: I just tried this with Access 2010 and the built-in date picker seems to work just fine on a linked table when the front-end database file is located in a folder where the user has just Read+Execute permissions. There may be something else at play in your particular case.

Comment: @Gord Thompson: I'm thinking that, too;  I was not able to reproduce the symptoms earlier today.  More to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a complete datepicker solution that is not ActiveX driven and works in all current Windows environments.  So, yes, there is a workaround.  However, it's just not possible to explain it in this forum.  It involves creating a new calendar form from scratch.  Besides, a lot of Active X functionality in 2K7 is spotty and most people are moving away from it.

Comment: Thanks, but I learned this phenomenon after replacing Gizmo's datepicker in an application that I just installed for a client.  I had not been aware of this business of the date picker being defeated by permissions.  I'm looking for something easier if possible.  Is your solution open source?  I have zero budget.

Comment: [Is this yours?](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=213963)

Comment: That particular one isn't mine, but from the description it has similar functionality.  Give it a whirl, any chance you get to replace ActiveX is gonna make your life easier.